# Converting a normal random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, variance, means

According to what I have learnt, a random variable, X, with mean, $\mu$ and standard deviation, $\sigma$, can be converted to the standardised variable, Z, using the formula: $$Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$

First question:
*Is there any derivation for this formula? Where does it come from?*

I have been told that the standard score allows us to calculate the probability of a score occurring within non-standard normal distribution and compare two scores from different normal distributions. The probability within a certain range can be obtained because of this: $$P(a<X<b) = P\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}<Z<\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$

Second question: *How does $Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ makes the area under the curve within the range of **a** and **b** for a non-standard normal distribution equal to the area under the curve within the range of $\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}$ and $\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}$ for a standard normal distribution?*

In my opinion: $$\int_a^\infty\frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}dx = \int_b^\infty\frac{e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dz $$

where the equation on the right is for non-standard normal distribution while the equation on the left is for standard normal distribution. Is my assumption that $b=\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}$ correct? If so, how to prove it?

There is a proof given by my teacher: $$mean = E(Z) = E\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = \frac{E(X)-\mu}{\sigma} = \frac{\mu-\mu}{\sigma} = 0$$ $$Var(Z) = Var\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = \frac{Var(X)-0}{\sigma^2} = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2} = 1$$

In this proof, it states that if $Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$, $\mu$ = 0 and $\sigma^2$ = 1. How does this proof tell us that $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ maps any normal distribution X to the Standard Normal distribution Z? And I still don't understand the relationship between this proof and the equivalence of area for a non-standard normal distribution and a standard normal distribution as stated above. Could someone help me? I really appreciate it.

Comment: From the integral $\int_a^\infty \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} dx$ you can apply the substitution $z=(x-\mu)/\sigma$ (and $dz = \frac{1}{\sigma} dx$ to obtain $\int_{(a-\mu)/\sigma}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2} \, dz$.

Comment: What I have learnt from your explanation is that $P(X>a) = P(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}>\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma})$ must be right while converting a non-standard normal distribution to a standard normal distribution. It doesn't matter what the value **a** is. So $z = (x-\mu)/\sigma$ is applicable to any value of x. Do I misunderstand what you are trying to convey?

Comment: $Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ will have mean $0$ and variance and standard deviation $1$, as a simple change of location and scale without changing the shape of the distribution.  If $X$ has a normal distribution then $Z$ will have a standard normal distribution, if not then not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can verify it by writing the pdf of $X$, then calculate the pdf of $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ using the change of variable formula.
   $$f_Z(z)=f_X(x)\cdot\left|\frac{dx}{dz}\right|=f_X(\mu+\sigma z)\cdot \sigma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}$$
2. You can make the change of variable $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ in the integral
3. Your teacher considers as known (maybe without proof) that a linear transformation of a normal variable is normal. So he only calculates the mean and variance.

**EDIT:** if you don't know or haven't learned yet the [change of variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function) formula you can deduce it as following:

$F_z(z)=P(Z\le z)=P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\le z\right)=P(X\le \mu+\sigma z)=F_X(\mu+\sigma z)$

And by differentiation with respect to $z$ (with chain rule):

$f_Z(z)=f_X(\mu+\sigma z)\cdot \sigma$

It is also proved [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239588/derivation-of-change-of-variables-of-a-probability-density-function).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I don't understand the reason why $f_Z(z)=f_X(x)\cdot\left|\frac{dx}{dz}\right|$. Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: I edited my answer to explain.